# Close Bootstrap navbar dropdown on mouse out is bad on small devices

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap navbar with one (or more) dropdown(s). I want to hide an open dropdown on mouse out, and so far so good with this very simple script that removes the "open" class:

```
var nav = $(".nav");
nav.children("li").hover(function(){
    console.log("mouse over");
}, function(){
    console.log("mouse out");
    $(this).removeClass("open");
});
```

Here comes two problems:

1. Even on small devices, where navbar is collapsed, open dropdown(s) suddenly close on mouse out 'cause of the previous script: this is obvious but it's not a nice behavior... so I try to leverage the
2. `hide.bs.dropdown` event, like this: `nav.trigger("hide.bs.dropdown");` but it doesn't work at all, and have no idea why...

Here's a [Bootply fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/P2ADmOyx2V) (you can see wrong behavior #1 at small resolutions clicking on the smartphone icon on top right)

So, how can I make it work? I could wrap the script into a `if ($(window).width() > [my breakpoint here])` statement, but I'd prefer not to rely on hardcoded brekpoints and go straight with what's yet in Bootstrap...

Thank you

Comment: does it have to be onclick or could you just use hover to make the dropdown active?

Comment: it should be on click only (for the "open on hover" I use the bootstrap-hover-dropdown plugin)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the mouse over mouse out effect to work primarily on desktop then it would be much easier to make your dropdown menu to appear on hover so that you can use media queries that will keep your collapsed menu working the same on mobile devices.  Some easy css will make this work

```
@media (min-width:769px) {
ul .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display:block;
}
ul .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  display:none;
}
}
```

Here's the bootply with a working example http://www.bootply.com/PB36wGEPPR#

Comment: Sorry, my fault: I forgot to mention that I'd like to mantain the "open dropdown only if clicked" behavior, not "open on hover"

Comment: Then you're only other solution will be to use more js to manipulate the behavior according to the window size.